# Performance issue with React controlled components

Tags: reactjs

I have been using react's controlled components in my application  and .

But I am noticing that as I enter more and more inputs to these form components my page is slowing down badly or even hangs sometime.

Any clue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you should look into the `key=""` attribute. Most often when react starts to slow down it is related to it doing more work than necessary.
Another way to improve performance is implementing `shouldComponentUpdate`, but that should first be necessary later on.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks Emil.

Comment: I am having the same issue, but I am not sure if I too should add the `key` attribute? I am not looping over some data to print a list or something using a `.map`. I have a list of `<Grid/>` components that are statically rendered.

Comment: @maverick only dynamically rendered items should have a `key`. If `key` is missing and needed, then it should, in the later version of React, be written as warnings in the developer console.

Comment: Well, I'm noticing the same performance issues, as every onChange event changes state, and thus the components is re-rendered. That has a big impact on performance.